# Как удалять последний символ в поле ввода при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: javascript

Есть два поля ввода, в первое я ввожу текст, во второй он появляется. Это всё делается двумя функциями:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var str = '';

    function edt1KeyUp(){
        var edt2 = document.getElementById('edt2');
        var edt1 = document.getElementById('edt1');
        edt2.value += str ? str : edt1.value;
        str = '';
        edt1.value = '';
    }

    function edt1KeyDown(){
        var edt1 = document.getElementById('edt1');
        str += edt1.value;
        edt1.value = '';
    }
    function backspace() {
        var edt2 = document.getElementById('edt2');
    }
</script>
```

Но если я случайно не то напечатал, то переходить на следующее поле и нажимать backspace не удобно, поэтому нужна такая функция для button, которая будет удалять один последний символ каждый раз при нажатии:

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="edt1" onkeyup="edt1KeyUp()" onkeydown="edt1KeyDown()" />
    <input type="button" value="<=" onClick="backspace()"><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="edt2"/>
</body>
```

Какими способами можно это реализовать:?

Comment: @chuikoff Уважаемый участник, старайтесь писать заголовок вопроса, более верно отражающий суть проблемы: это существенно повышает качество вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавайте событие в обработчик

```
<input type="text" id="edt1" onkeyup="edt1KeyUp()" onkeydown="edt1KeyDown(event)" />
```

и отслеживайте код нажатой клавиши

```
function edt1KeyDown(e){
    var edt1 = document.getElementById('edt1');
    str += edt1.value;
    edt1.value = '';

    var edt2 = document.getElementById("edt2");
    if (e.keyCode == 8) { // backspace
        edt2.value = edt2.value.substring(0, edt2.value.length - 1);
    }
}
```

Можно обойтись и без вспомогательного буфера, наблюдая за всеми нажатиями и используя preventDefault() для предотвращения появления символов в первом поле.

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>  
<script>      
    var str = '';

    function edt1KeyUp(){
        edt2.value += str ? str : edt1.value;
        str = '';
        edt1.value = '';
    }

    function edt1KeyDown(){
        str += edt1.value;
        edt1.value = '';
    }
    function backspace() {
        edt2.value = edt2.value.substring(0, edt2.value.length - 1);
    }
</script>   
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="edt1" onkeyup="edt1KeyUp()" onkeydown="edt1KeyDown()" />
    <input type="button" value="<=" onClick="backspace()"><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="edt2"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Переписал функцию backspace() - все работает.

Comment: Доставать элемент по id не нужно, так как edt1 и edt2 уже существуют как переменные, которые содержат в себе данные.